# Relation between total pulse energy and electric field of a THZ pulse

Tags: optics, laser

We've this relation between the total energy of generated THz pulse and the electric field of the THz pulse.

$$J_{THz}=c\varepsilon_0\int [E_{THz}(r,t)]^2rdrd\varphi dt
\quad\text{(eqn. 1)}$$

Where does eqn. 1 come from?

Assuming it to be correct, upon simplification, it boils down to

$$J_{THz}=c\varepsilon_0 K_{eff}^2\frac{J_{opt}^2}{A_{opt}}
\quad\text{(eqn. 2)}$$

I assumed the eqn. 1 to be true and arrived at eqn. 2 after a simple calculation but where does eqn. 1 come from?

Note:
$$E_{THz}(r,t)=K_{eff}T(t)\frac{2J_{opt}}{A_{opt}}\exp\left ( -\frac{2r^2}{r^2_{opt}} \right )\\
K_{eff}=\mathrm{const.}\\
\int T(t)^2dt=1 $$

We can assume everything else to be constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eqn. 1 can be derived from the expression for energy density in an electromagnetic field in a vacuum,
$u = \frac{\epsilon_0 E^2}{2} + \frac{B^2}{2 \mu_0} .$

For electromagnetic waves in a vacuum $E = cB$, so the expression simplifies to $u = \epsilon_0 E^2$. Therefore integrating in cylindrical coordinates and substituting $z = c t$ for the axial coordinate gives the expression for the total pulse energy,

$J_{THz} = \int u \left ( r , z \right ) r dr d \varphi dz = c\epsilon_0 \int \left [ E \left ( r , t \right ) \right ]^2 r dr d \varphi dt$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was after this question for two hours, it felt like it's something related to density since we're carrying out a volume integral, but I didn't think deeper enough.